# How to add an input field for an add to cart button?

Tags: html, input, cart

I am trying to build an ecommerce site on bigcartel.  The product page does not have a quantity field and I would like to add one.  There is limited backend access but I can modify the html and add javascript.

Without too much trouble, is there any way to add a quantity field linked to the cart button?

Here is the code from the cart button area:

```
 <div id="variations">
  {% if product.available? %}
    <p>
      <select id="cart_variation_id">
        <option>Select Option...</option>
        {% for variation in product.variations %}
          {% if variation.available? %}
            <option value="{{ variation.id }}">{{ variation.name }} - {{ variation.price | money }}</option>
          {% else %}
            <option disabled="disabled">{{ variation.name }} - {{ variation.price | money }} (Out of Stock)</option>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      </select>

      <button class="btn" onclick="javascript:Store.cart.add(document.getElementById('cart_variation_id').options[document.getElementById('cart_variation_id').selectedIndex].value);return false;">Add to Cart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own button which is linked to a html `<input>` field called quantity, and use javascript to call `Store.cart.add...` quantity number of times. You will have to add extra JS to allow only numbers in input.

Looks like currently its adding to cart with `onclick="javascript:Store.cart.add(document.getElementById('cart_variation_id').options[document.getElementById('cart_variation_id').selectedIndex].value)`

So if you wanted to add a quantity feature a 'ghetto' fix would be to have a for loop call this method quantity number of times, assuming it updates your cart quantity.